# Best tool to create casual link chart/evidence board

Tags: graphs, time-management, productivity, charts, linked-data

I would like to have a space, kind of like a scrapbook, where I can **link specific pieces of information** based on **some mutual trait** that they share (e.g. link news articles about a specific event to which they relate to). These blobs (for lack of better word) should ideally be **complex enough** to hold **some metadata** like a hyperlink to said article, its publish date and a small note, **but generally** on the macro view **only** its **name** and maybe a **small thumbnail** should be visible.

The blobs would obviously **link to specific people, organisations or events** in a cluster-like fashion, and these higher order blobs **can also link to eachother**, ideally limitlessly (in both breadth and depth). Overall, I am not too concerned over the linking capability, a simple many-to-many relationship will do fine, of course ideally some sort of inheritance would be useful, so that it's easy to trace child/parent blobs of the blob you're looking at. Tagging can also be useful: "show me all articles tagged with "2022"", etc.

Ideally it would be stored on the cloud, but software you run locally is also ok. Either way it should be either free, have a one-time (affordable) licence or be pennies/mo if it's a subscription service. I suspect my needs will be met by any "free" tier that most companies offer, I won't be storing gigantic charts.

Most of the websites or software I've tried usually have a such a complicated linking system that it's a pain to create charts quickly and casually, but generally none of them offer for individual nodes to store metadata, let alone thumbnails. They are clearly focused towards building organisational or procedural graphs.

I am not convinced that a tool that covers all of these requirements exists yet, so I would like to hear your suggestions - even if it doesn't cover all things I will still give it a go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is Paterva's Maltego! There used to be a walled-off investigation-specific program they used to offer as well; but now it appears to all be spun together as just ["Maltego"](https://www.maltego.com/)...

OK! Yes indeed! In September 2020 Maltego did some rebranding apparently. The offline investigation software is CaseFile or [Maltego CaseFile](https://docs.maltego.com/support/solutions/articles/15000018948-what-is-maltego-casefile-#:%7E:text=CaseFile%20is%20Maltego%27s%20answer%20to%20the) now.

*"CaseFile is Maltego's answer to the offline intelligence problem, it allows for analysts to examine links between offline data"*

The Community Edition (CE) is 'register & free' for both.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This has most of the things I am looking for, thank you.